# Optimise query with Group By and Count

Tags: mysql, sql

Would like advice to optimise the query below, as it currently takes about 20 seconds to process on first run, depending on the amount of users being selected and the date range.

The purpose is to return a count of each code, per user.

There are 27 codes and each user has an am and pm attendance record.

```
SELECT user,
    code,
    COUNT(code) AS total
FROM attendances AS attendances
WHERE attendances.user IN ('abc123', 'abc456', 'abc789')
    AND (
        attendances.date >= '2019-10-06' AND attendances.date <= '2019-10-11'
    )
GROUP BY user, code
```

**Table Definiton**

[image]

**Indexes**

Each of these fields has an index

```
location
source_id
date
user_recorded
code
user
```

**EXPLAIN Result**

[image]

Comment: column `attendance_code` referenced in the GROUP BY clause does not appear in the SELECT list.  Why? Is `code` functionally dependent on `attendance_code` ? Are we wanting to return just any value of `code` ?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. test `GROUP BY user, code`.

Comment: please run an explain query and share the result. Also, you are grouping by attendance_code but it is not part of your select statement. Please check.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your table?

Comment: If `attendance_code` in the GROUP BY clause is replaced with `code` (column referenced in the SELECT list), then the optimal covering index (for the query) is likely **`...ON attendances (user,code,date)`**  
That should allow MySQL to avoid a "Using filesort" operation by using the index to satisfy the GROUP BY, and allow the query to be satisfied entirely from the index without looking up data pages from the underlying table. Use `EXPLAIN` to see execution plan. Alternatively, we could try an index with user and date as the leading columns (more limiting the rows accessed).

Comment: How many colums has the table ?

Comment: Thanks for responses have edited the question to add additional context

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT user, code,
       COUNT(code) AS total
FROM attendances a
WHERE a.user IN ('abc123', 'abc456', 'abc789') AND
      a.date >= '2019-10-06' AND a.date <= '2019-10-11'
GROUP BY user, code;
```

You have a problem.  An index on both `user` and `date` will not be used in an index (in MySQL).

One method is `union all` with an index on `(user, date, code)`:

```
(SELECT user, code, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM attendances a
 WHERE a.user = 'abc123'
       a.date >= '2019-10-06' AND a.date <= '2019-10-11'
 GROUP BY user, code
) UNION ALL
(SELECT user, code, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM attendances a
 WHERE a.user = 'abc456'
       a.date >= '2019-10-06' AND a.date <= '2019-10-11'
 GROUP BY user, code
) UNION ALL
(SELECT user, code, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM attendances a
 WHERE a.user = 'abc789'
       a.date >= '2019-10-06' AND a.date <= '2019-10-11'
 GROUP BY user, code
);
```

This can make direct use of the index and should be much faster.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't make a difference

Comment: @DanReil . . . Do you have the specified 3-part index?

Comment: @GordanLinoff sorry what do you mean by 3-part index?

Comment: @DanReil . . . The index in the answer has three keys in it.

Comment: @gordonlindoff at the moment I have 3 separate indexes in each column date, code and user

Comment: @DanReil . . . And that is not coming from this answer.  It specifies a very particular index.